WebSocket connection error in React and Docker: Could not connect to WebSocket to ws://backend:7000/api/getData
When running my React app in Docker using Nginx as a reverse proxy, I get an error when connecting to WebSocket. I get an error message:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://backend:7000/api/getData' failed: WebSocket error

When running my React app in Docker using Nginx as a reverse proxy, I get an error when connecting to WebSocket. I get an error message:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://backend:7000/api/getData' failed: WebSocket error
However, locally everything works perfectly. The problem only occurs in Docker.
The backend (Go) is configured to handle WebSocket requests and also works with Redis to receive data.
When trying to connect React client code to a WebSocket server that is located in a Docker container, an error occurs.
How to fix this problem?
here is my docker-compose:
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./front/app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    restart: always

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"
    restart: always

  bot:
    build:
      context: ./bot_crypto/crypto
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    restart: always

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
      - bot
    restart: always

nginx:
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend:3000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://backend:7000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        
    }
}

frontend:
import { name_table } from "data/data";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { DataGetProps } from "interfaces/data.props";
import Filter from "components/filter/filter";
import NProgress from "nprogress";
const Content = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<DataGetProps[]>([]);
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState<WebSocket | null>(null);
    const [time, setTime] = useState<string>("");
    const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState<DataGetProps[]>([])
    const [stateFilter, setStateFilter] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const [stateFilterNum, setFilterNum]=useState<number>(0)



    useEffect(() => {

        const newSocket = new WebSocket("ws://backend:7000/api/getData");
        setSocket(newSocket);


        return () => {
            newSocket.close();
        };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!socket) return;



        socket.onmessage = (event) => {
            NProgress.start();

            const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
            setData(message.data);
            setTime(new Date().toLocaleString());
            setStateFilter(true)
            NProgress.done();

            console.log(message);
        };


        socket.onerror = (error) => {
            console.error("WebSocket error:", error);
        };


        return () => {
            socket.close();
        };
    }, [socket]);

    return (
        <div className="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
            <div className="max-w-max  grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 px-4">
                <div className={"text-center"} > Обновление: {time}</div>
                <Filter data={data}   setFilterData={setFilterData} stateFilter={stateFilter} setStateFilter={setStateFilter} stateFilterNum={stateFilterNum} setFilterNum={setFilterNum}/>

                <div className={"grid grid-cols-6 gap-4"}>
                    {name_table && name_table.map((item) => (
                        <div key={item.id} className="p-4 bg-gray-200 text-center rounded">
                            <div className={"text-black font-bold"}>{item.name}</div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
                {filterData && filterData.map((item) => (
                    <div key={item.id} className={"grid grid-cols-6 gap-4"}>
                        <div className="p-4 bg-gray-200 text-center rounded">{item.symbol}</div>
                        <div className="p-4 bg-gray-200 text-center rounded">{item.exchange1}</div>
                        <div className="p-4 bg-gray-200 text-center rounded">{item.price1}</div>
                        <div className="p-4 bg-gray-200 text-center rounded">{item.exchange2}</div>
                        <div className="p-4 bg-gray-200 text-center rounded">{item.price2}</div>
                        <div className="p-4 bg-gray-200 text-center rounded">{item.spread}</div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Content;

Golang:
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/codeza-org/backend_crypto/connect"
    "github.com/go-redis/redis/v8"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2/middleware/cors"
    "github.com/gofiber/websocket/v2"
    "time"
)

type Comparison struct {
    ID        string  `json:"id"`
    Symbol    string  `json:"symbol"`
    Exchange1 string  `json:"exchange1"`
    Price1    float64 `json:"price1"`
    Exchange2 string  `json:"exchange2"`
    Price2    float64 `json:"price2"`
    Spread    float64 `json:"spread"`
}

var client *redis.Client

func main() {
    
    var err error
    client, err = connect.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    app := fiber.New()
    app.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
        AllowOrigins: "http://frontend:3000",
    }))

    app.Use("api/getData", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        if websocket.IsWebSocketUpgrade(c) {
            return c.Next()
        }
        return fiber.ErrUpgradeRequired
    }, websocket.New(getData))

    app.Post("api/data", data)

    app.Listen(":7000")
}

func data(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    var comparisons []Comparison

    if err := c.BodyParser(&comparisons); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    
    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(comparisons)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    
    err = client.Set(client.Context(), "data", jsonData, 0).Err()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fmt.Println("Данные успешно записаны в Redis")

    return c.JSON(fiber.Map{
        "message": "Данные успешно получены и обработаны",
    })
}

func getData(c *websocket.Conn) {
    for {
        fmt.Println(1)
        
        if c == nil {
            fmt.Println("Соединение WebSocket закрыто")
            return
        }

    
        val, err := client.Get(client.Context(), "data").Result()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Ошибка при получении данных из Redis:", err)
            return
        }

        
        var comparisons []Comparison
        err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(val), &comparisons)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Ошибка при разборе данных JSON:", err)
            return
        }

        
        data, err := json.Marshal(fiber.Map{"data": comparisons})
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Ошибка при преобразовании данных в JSON:", err)
            return
        }

        
        err = c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, data)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Ошибка при отправке данных через WebSocket:", err)
            return
        }

        из Redis
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }
}


The browser application runs in the end user's browser, even if its code is served from a container, and it can't directly use the Docker-internal hostnames; also see "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend.  I wonder if it would work to have Nginx also proxy the Websocket connection, and connect to ws:/api/getData, without a host name in the URL?

@DavidMaze So the best thing for me is to wrap it all in a vds server, buy a domain and install it and start working with the domain?

Why is your frontend accessing ws://backend:7000/api/getData? If everything is running under docker on your local machine then I'd expect the url to be ws://127.0.0.1:80/api/getData (because you want to connect via the proxy; backend is unlikely to even resolve to an IP on the host). Note that the proxy will request this as ws://backend:7000//getData so some tweaks will be needed.
